# Replace Javascript ID's with Clases for HTML5 Video Controls

Tags: javascript, html

I've replaced all ID's with Classes in the HTML and in the Javascript for the Video Player, but it's still doesn't work. I"m a newbie in javascript so I'm going to need some help to figure out why it's not runing the way that it should.

Here's a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/k37Bs/

The updated JS suggested by Chris Ferdinandi still doesnt work. The JS is pasted below:
I replaced the Add Event Listener code completely and removed the setobject reference section of codes, still no dice. Any further help will be greatly appreciated.

```
//----------------------------Video Player--------------------------------------

var vid, playbtn, seekslider, curtimetext, durtimetext, mutebtn, volumeslider, fullscreenbtn; 

//--------Functions------------------------------

// Initialize Player

function intializePlayer(){ 

window.onload = intializePlayer; 

// Play/Pause Function
function playPause(){ 
if(vid.paused){ 
vid.play(); 
playbtn.style.background = "url(pause.png)"; 
} else { vid.pause(); 
playbtn.style.background = "url(play.png)"; 
} 
}

// Video Seek Function
function vidSeek(){ 
var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
vid.currentTime = seekto; 
}


// Seektime Update

function seektimeupdate(){ 

var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration); 
seekslider.value = nt; 
var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60); 
var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60); 
var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60); 
if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs; } 
if(dursecs < 10){ dursecs = "0"+dursecs; } 
if(curmins < 10){ curmins = "0"+curmins; } 
if(durmins < 10){ durmins = "0"+durmins; } 
curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins+":"+cursecs; 
durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins+":"+dursecs; 
} 


// Mute Function
function vidmute(){ 
if(vid.muted){ 
vid.muted = false; 
mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute"; 
} else { 
vid.muted = true; 
mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
 } 
 }

 // Set Volume Function
function setvolume(){ vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100; } 


 // Full Screen Function
function toggleFullScreen(){ 
if(vid.requestFullScreen){ 
vid.requestFullScreen(); 
} else if(vid.webkitRequestFullScreen){ 
  vid.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
  } else if(vid.mozRequestFullScreen){ vid.mozRequestFullScreen(); 
  } 
}


 // ------------Add event listeners-----------------------------------------

 var i;

for (i = 0; i < playbtn.length; i++) {
    playbtn[i].addEventListener("click",playPause,false); 
}
for (i = 0; i < seekslider.length; i++) {
    seekslider[i].addEventListener("change",vidSeek,false); 
}

for (i = 0; i < vid.length; i++) {
    vid[i].addEventListener("timeupdate",seektimeupdate,false); 
}
for (i = 0; i < seekslider.length; i++) {
   mutebtn[i].addEventListener("click",vidmute,false); 
}

for (i = 0; i < vid.length; i++) {
    volumeslider[i].addEventListener("change",setvolume,false); 
}
for (i = 0; i < seekslider.length; i++) {
  fullscreenbtn[i].addEventListener("click",toggleFullScreen,false); 
}

}
```

The Original JS:

```
//----------------------------Video Player--------------------------------------

var vid, playbtn, seekslider, curtimetext, durtimetext, mutebtn, volumeslider, fullscreenbtn; 

//--------Functions------------------------------

// Initialize Player

function intializePlayer(){ 

window.onload = intializePlayer; 

// Play/Pause Function
function playPause(){ 
if(vid.paused){ 
vid.play(); 
playbtn.style.background = "url(pause.png)"; 
} else { vid.pause(); 
playbtn.style.background = "url(play.png)"; 
} 
}

// Video Seek Function
function vidSeek(){ 
var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
vid.currentTime = seekto; 
}


// Seektime Update

function seektimeupdate(){ 

var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration); 
seekslider.value = nt; 
var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60); 
var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60); 
var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60); 
if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs; } 
if(dursecs < 10){ dursecs = "0"+dursecs; } 
if(curmins < 10){ curmins = "0"+curmins; } 
if(durmins < 10){ durmins = "0"+durmins; } 
curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins+":"+cursecs; 
durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins+":"+dursecs; 
} 


// Mute Function
function vidmute(){ 
if(vid.muted){ 
vid.muted = false; 
mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute"; 
} else { 
vid.muted = true; 
mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
 } 
 }

 // Set Volume Function
function setvolume(){ vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100; } 


 // Full Screen Function
function toggleFullScreen(){ 
if(vid.requestFullScreen){ 
vid.requestFullScreen(); 
} else if(vid.webkitRequestFullScreen){ 
  vid.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
  } else if(vid.mozRequestFullScreen){ vid.mozRequestFullScreen(); 
  } 
}




//----------------Set object references-------------------------------------
 vid = document.getElementsByClassName("my_video"); 

playbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("playpausebtn"); 

seekslider = document.getElementsByClassName("seekslider"); 

curtimetext = document.getElementsByClassName("curtimetext"); 

durtimetext = document.getElementsByClassName("durtimetext"); 

mutebtn = document.getElementsByClassName("mutebtn"); 

volumeslider = document.getElementsByClassName("volumeslider"); 

fullscreenbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreenbtn"); 




 // ------------Add event listeners-----------------------------------------

playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause,false); 

seekslider.addEventListener("change",vidSeek,false); 

vid.addEventListener("timeupdate",seektimeupdate,false); 

mutebtn.addEventListener("click",vidmute,false); 

volumeslider.addEventListener("change",setvolume,false); 

fullscreenbtn.addEventListener("click",toggleFullScreen,false); 

}
```

The HTML:

```
 <div id="evid">

 <video class="videogunshots" width="550" height="300"> 
<source src="file:///C|/Users/Godsnake/Desktop/July14/content/gunshots.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="file:///C|/Users/Godsnake/Desktop/July14/content/gunshots.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="file:///C|/Users/Godsnake/Desktop/July14/content/gunshots.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 
  </video> 


 <div class="videocontrols"> 
 <button class="playpausebtn" onclick="playPause()">Play</button> 
 <input class="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
 <span class="curtimetext">00:00</span> / <span class="durtimetext">00:00</span>
 <button class="mutebtn">Mute</button>
 <input class="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
 <button class="fullscreenbtn">[ &nbsp; ]</button>
 </div>


</div>
```

On a different note the video I"m playing doesnt seem to fit the container with Object-fit:fill any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements rather than just a single element. In order to attach an event listener, you will need to loop through each one and attach individually.

Something like this:

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < playbtn.length; i++) {
    playbtn[i].addEventListener("click",playPause,false); 
}
for (i = 0; i < seekslider.length; i++) {
    seekslider[i].addEventListener("change",vidSeek,false); 
}
...
```

**Update:**

I just took a look at your JSFiddle. You're calling local resources (things on your computer) that cannot be accessed on the web. The buttons, even the file itself, need to live on a server where they can be accessed. Until that happens, none of this will work.

One of the biggest things that helped me when I was learning was figuring out how to use the console in Chrome Developer Tools (Firefox has a good set of tools as well). Any errors will get spat out there.

Comment: So you're saying to change all the set-object references:       playbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("playpausebtn"); 
 
seekslider = document.getElementsByClassName("seekslider");

Comment: Not sure I understand the comment here?

Comment: Im going to need more instructions than that. What I understand so far is that you only have to change the Event Listeners portion of the code by adding var i for..etc.  Is that all I need to make it run?

Comment: You already have the variables set. What they return is a collection of elements (vs getElementByID which returns a single element). For each collection of elements, write a for loop using the syntax noted above. This loop cycles through each item and adds the listener to it.

Comment: Haven't you already defined the playbtn, seekslider, etc. variables in the script above?

Comment: So I should remove the object refereces section and the add event listeners section and replace it with the code above for each collection of elements?

Comment: I made changes to the code according to what I think you meant, but as you can see it's still not working. I would greatly appreciated if you go over the updated code again, point out the errors, and show me a complete sample of what I have to do. Step by step. Remember I'm a novice in js. Thanks again.